# Issue with react-datepicker and redux form/immutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, immutability, redux-form

i'm using a react-datepicker module which is compatible with redux-form like this:

```
<DatePicker
      {...props.input}
      dateFormat="DD-MM-YYYY"
      selected={props.input.value
        ? moment(props.input.value, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
        : moment()}
      disabled={props.disabled}
    />
```

The issue is that when i click inside my datepicker and select a date thousands errors are occuring like the following  "Error serializing unrecognized object Thu Apr 20 2017 17:44:12 GMT+0300" Im using redux form immutable which is a demand for my project. Any ideas of how to solve this? Maybe editing the react-datepicker somehow would be a solution?

Comment: If you think it is an immutable related issue, have you made sure you are  using the immutable version of reducer? `import { reducer  } from 'redux-form/immutable';`

Comment: Of course i'm using import { reducer } from 'redux-form/immutable :)

Comment: You did not provide a mvce (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I cannot assume you have used a correct reducer.

Comment: import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form/immutable';

Comment: You are right my fault

Comment: No worries. Sorry I don't mean to make you feel bad. There is just too little information in the question...

Comment: Yes i know it, i've searched for this question a lot but i cant find a solution. That's why i post here.